# Does Windows 8.1 ( not Pro or Enterprise) support IIS and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, windows-8.1

If I buy a computer with the Windows 8.1 operating system ( not Professional or Enterprise version), will I be able to install IIS  on it and do development with ASP.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I use it on my windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: It doesn't however support Windows authentication, for which you need to upgrade to pro.